# Symfony 3.3.2 Method ReflectionMethod::__toString()

Tags: php, symfony

I had fresh install symfony (3.3.2) project on Debian 8, PHP 5.6, but I have issue when running web application.

> PHP Fatal error:  Method ReflectionMethod::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Resource/ReflectionClassResource.php on line 0, referer:

I see this message after composer completes symfony installation and tries to clean cache, also web is not working and in error_log is this error.

Can't find solution for this problem, or it's Symfony bug?

Comment: In some case you should remove the entire ./var/* content

Comment: Yeah, seems Symfony caching caused this problem, only 1 way to fix is to manually delete va/r content.